# How to export a docker image to a rootfs without starting a container?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image, rootfs

I wanna save a docker image to a rootfs format(like a dir consisting of `/etc /var ...`), which is just like what `docker export` does. Also `docker save` cannot meet my need too because it saves layers of the image other than the dir they mount together. But I do not want to use `docker export` because it only works when a container using this image is running. Now I have an image list containing about 1000 entries, how can I save every image to rootfs without starting a container first on each of them?

Comment: Just a thought: iterate through your images, use `docker create ...` to create a container (with `create` it won't start), then use `docker export ...` and finally cleanup with `docker rm ...`.

Comment: @tgogos thx a lot. I thought `docker export` would not work on stopped containers.  But I tried and found it worked!

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @lucasvc's answer, here is a one-liner to do it:

```
docker export $(docker create <image id>) --output="latest.tar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [@tgogos comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723481/how-to-export-a-docker-image-to-a-rootfs-without-starting-a-container#comment94303787_53723481):

> iterate through your images, use `docker create ...` to create a container (with create it won't start), then use `docker export ...` and finally cleanup with `docker rm ...`

Answer (score 3):

I just open sourced [undocker](https://git.jakstys.lt/motiejus/undocker/), which can convert docker image layers to a rootfs tarball:

```
$ skopeo copy docker://docker.io/busybox:latest docker-archive:busybox.tar
$ undocker busybox.tar - | tar -tv
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0         1149184 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/[[ link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/acpid link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/add-shell link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/addgroup link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/adduser link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/adjtimex link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/ar link to bin/[
hrwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-05-17 22:07 bin/arch link to bin/[
...
```

Comment: The link is broken because it was apparently moved to https://git.jakstys.lt/motiejus/undocker